# c++ compatibility with older libraries

Tags: c++, struct

I have a library 1-1.h.

```
#include <1-1.h>;
```

Which has a struct:

```
struct bucket { ... }
```

Unfortunately this library is 3-party and they have changed the struct bucket to bucket_t { ... } in 1.2. All my code uses bucket but I would also like it compatible with bucket_t.

Is it possible to:

```
#ifndef bucket
    typedef bucket_t bucket;
#endif
```

(Code doesn't work but I would like to set bucket to bucket_t if it exists. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just use bucket_t all the time

Comment: For users who are using 1-1.h not 1-2.h. I have no control over this library but I still want my code to work both ways.

Comment: Your `#ifndef bucket` code would work if library 1-1 defined bucket: `#define bucket`

Comment: @Derek correct if he just looks at the .h file he should be able to make it work

Comment: @Derek it doesn't seem to, that was just sample code to try and show what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user622469 `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are preprocessor directives that check whether a macro is defined (or not defined). I think you are trying to use them as if they check to see if a struct is defined.

Comment: @Derek Like I said, it's pseudo code... just trying to show you guys that: If that structure is present (from the include) redefine it as bucket_t. Not sure this is possible so if you have any leads please let me know.

Comment: Does the library define any sort of version macro? easier to base it of that. e.g `#if VERSION_1_2`

Comment: @user622469 I missed where you said it's pseudo code :). Anyway, your code would be fine if the class that provides the definition of the bucket struct *also* defined a BUCKET macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add your own predefined symbol in your project or makefile that specifies which version you are using. Something like LIBRARY1_1 or LIBRARY1_2. If neither are defined report an error. You can do this by using your own include file like below.

If the header file is different for each version you use...

**my1-1.h**

```
#if defined( LIBRARY1_1 )
#include <1-1.h>
#elif defined( LIBRARY1_2 )
#include <1-2.h>
typedef bucket_t bucket
#else
#error Please define LIBRARY1_1 or LIBRARY1_2 before including this file
#endif
```

If the same filename is used for the header in each version...

**my1-1.h**

```
#include <1-1.h>
#if defined( LIBRARY1_1 )
#elif defined( LIBRARY1_2 )
typedef bucket_t bucket
#else
#error Please define LIBRARY1_1 or LIBRARY1_2 before including this file
#endif
```

Comment: I get an: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct bucket_t bucket’

Comment: updated. Forgot to place the includes inside of the #if/#elif blocks ;) Sorry bout that

Comment: error: aggregate ‘bucket t’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: The example is based on the information you have provided in your question. You may need to make adjustments but without additional information I can't provide any more specific information.

Comment: I compiled a minimal example with what you posted and this is correct. There is something wrong with my code. Thank you.

Comment: Ah. Hopefully the compiler will give you enough information in the error messages that you can trace it. Upgrading to new libraries can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor knows more or less nothing about the language.

I would opt for something like the following.
Either in the source file including the library, or write a header to avoid repeating yourself.

```
#if USE_LIBRARY_1_1
#include <1-1.h>
#elif USE_LIBRARY_1_2
#include <1-2.h>
typedef bucket_t bucket
#endif
```